# Connection speed requirements for Sync Framework

Tags: sql-server, client-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I am designing a system where I have to keep in-sync Client databases with the Server database. There is one central Server (SQL Server 2008 with 20 tables) and around 30 Clients (SQL Server or SQL Server CE). Client won't need all the 20 tables but 10 would be a fair guess. This is a medical system in nature and it would be dealing with maximum 1200 patients so it's not a huge system. System is going to be deployed in very remote areas where internet won't be always available so I need some DB sync technology. Client DB will be synced with the Server once internet becomes available. After reading about available technologies I am inclined towards using Microsoft Sync.

My question is regarding the connection speed requirements for Microsoft Sync Framework. Client will be deployed in very remote areas. Internet will be available for short durations and internet speed will be very slow (Let's say download would be 20KB/sec Max).

I am concerned regarding the performance of Sync Framework in this kind of Internet speed. Are there any benchmarks which can give me an idea about estimated time of Sync with different connection speed values? Does it make sense to use Sync Framework when internet speed is this slow (for example 20KB/Sec). Will slow speed only effect in terms of time it takes to complete the sync or are there any other drawbacks as well?

I have no prior experience with DB sync technologies. This is first time I am doing something of this nature. If I am missing something major or this is not the right way to go in this kind of scenario, feel free to share your thoughts and ideas.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine to use Sync Framework for your task.  The duration of the sync will be determined by the number of changes that have to be uploaded/downloaded from/to the server. In your case, if you cannot guarantee a connection it takes for the entire sync to complete, you will have to use the Batching in Sync Framework to break up your sync into smaller chunks.

You can maybe use this as a starting point: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sync/archive/2010/09/24/how-to-sync-large-sql-server-databases-to-sql-azure.aspx

To test out how long your sync transactions might take to execute, setup a test scenario and then you can enable the Tracing components in Sync Framework to trace the sync process:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc807160.aspx

Answer (score 0):

it's not just the number of changes that will affect the performance, but the size as well. a 10 row change can have each row at 5k or contain a 1MB blob.

if by batching you mean setting the memory data cache size, it also does not batch the application of changes, it batches the sending of the changes over the wire.

sync fx is just like any other database app, you should take into consideration locking, concurrency, etc...

on a busy system, sync will take time if it has to wait for locks to be released.